# Setting up "graph coordinates" on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

The following is stated in Example 1.4 of *Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

[image]

Now when the author says that $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of the function $$x^i = f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1})$$ I assume he means that $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the image of the function $f_i : \mathbb{B}^n \to U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ defined by $$f_i(x^1, \dots, x^n) = \left(x^1, \dots, x^{i-1}, \sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2 - \cdots, - (x^n)^2}, x^i, \dots, x^n\right)$$, i.e. 
$$U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n = \left\{\left(x^1, \dots, x^{i-1}, \sqrt{1-(x^1)^2- \cdots, - (x^n)^2}, x^i, \dots, x^n\right) \mid (x^1, \dots, x^n) \in \mathbb{B}^n\right\}$$
and since $$\left\{\left(x^1, \dots, x^{i-1}, \sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2 - \cdots, - (x^n)^2}, x^i, \dots, x^n\right) \mid (x^1, \dots, x^n) \in \mathbb{B}^n\right\}$$ is homeomorphic to $$\left\{\left(x^1, \dots, x^{i-1},  x^i, \dots, x^n, \sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2 - \cdots, - (x^n)^2}\right) \mid (x^1, \dots, x^n) \in \mathbb{B}^n\right\} = \Gamma(f)$$
 we can thus think of $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ as being the graph of the function $f$.

While this is slightly different from what the author has said, this is the only way I seem to able to interpret this rigorously. Have I interpreted this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've interpreted that correctly. But let me be clear that this is not "slightly different from what the author said" by looking at the case $n = 1$.

In this case, we have
$$
f(p) = \sqrt{1 - p^2}
$$

If we look at $(x_1, x_2)$ coordinates on the plane, then the third displayed equation, for $i = 1$, says that the right half-circle is the graph of 
$$
x_1 = \sqrt{1 - x_2^2}
$$

Perhaps slightly easier to make sense of, given how we like to do xy-plots, is the case $i = 2$, where it says that the upper half-circle is the graph of 
$$
x^2 = \sqrt{1 - x_1^2}
$$
or, in more down-to-earth terms, 
$$
y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}
$$
That happens ALSO to be the image of 
$$
t \mapsto (t, \sqrt{1-t^2})
$$
as you've observed, but in general, the graph of 
$$
y = f(x)
$$
is the same as the image of 
$$
t \mapsto (t, f(t))
$$
(for a suitably chosen domain for $t$, namely, the domain of $f$).